# Need better explanation as why we are using pointers to pointers in Binary search

Tags: c, pointers

I was just trying to grasp better understanding of pointers to pointers and on internet I found an example of Binary search where the developer used pointers to pointers in an insert function.

My question is:

1. What edge does the below code have over other BST code which uses single pointers?
2. At the end of insert function, the code uses a recursive method but I don't understand the syntax of using `&` in `insert(&(*tree)->right, item);`.

The `insert` function looks like this:

```
 void insert(node ** tree, node * item)  
 {   
   if(!(*tree))  
   {  
        *tree = item;  
        return;  
   }  
   if(item->val<(*tree)->val)  
      insert(&(*tree)->left, item);  
   else if(item->val>(*tree)->val)  
      insert(&(*tree)->right, item);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line, which assigns `tree` to item if it is null, i.e., it starts a new tree.

```
*tree = item;
```

If you only took a `node*` then you would not be able to assign a new value to it that would be visible from outside of the function.  This is because the pointer is passed by *value*, so the `insert` function would simply be modifying a copy of the original.

> 2) at the end of insert function the code uses recursive method but I didnt understadn teh syntax of using "&" insert(&(*tree)->right, item);

The `->` operator has a igher precedence than the `&` operator does, so it is passing in the address of `*tree->right`, i.e., the `node**` next in line.

Comment: Just for my knowledge. Couldnt I do something like             struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data) {  
  if (node == NULL) { 
    return(newNode(data)); 
  } 
  else { 
    if (data <= node->data) node->left = insert(node->left, data); 
    else node->right = insert(node->right, data);

    return(node);
  } 
}

Comment: HI Ed S. Thanks for explaination. You have helped me to clear my doubts. IN summary, if we want to change the value , we can pass that value as a pointer in a function. so on same pattern if we want to change the pointer, then in that case we have to pass it as pointers of pointers. Hope I am right.

Comment: more explaination for some one like me .............                   http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/pointers/article.php/c4089/     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913373/why-is-pointer-to-pointer-being-used-in-this-prog

Comment: Sounds like you've got it.  Since everything is passed by value, if you want the caller to see the value of an argument change you will need to pass a pointer, and that applies to pointers as well.